# How to set field values as labels in QGIS2 Print Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am mapping the distribution of 325 bird species, displaying circles in the grid cells each species occurs in. The data contains as many duplicates of the NAME as there are cells in which it occurs. I produce a map by filtering for a NAME then want to print the maps using the NAME field in a label as a caption below the map. I would like to have it generated automatically rather than write it in manually - in anticipation of being able to generate all species maps as an Atlas (that's another issue).

So far, all I get by using `[% name %]` is `[name]`, not the species name. Any ideas of what I might be missing? Nothing I've found by searching has helped so far.

Answer (score 4):

`[% name %]` will only be evaluated when at print time when printing using the Atlas option.

It will be shown as `[name]` until you print.

Comment: Thanks for that. The print copies also had the [name] error. I just tried again by adding a new name-only shapefile and using that as the Coverage Layer, and it worked fine for the name. Problem is, then it prints the Atlas maps with the names but keeps the map the same. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Do you have a `name` field in your grid coverage layer.  Can you post a picture of your atlas panel and the attribute table.

Comment: I have a NAME field in the main layer, but because there are 1000s of records, the Atlas tries to print them all (I had to abort an attempt at it earlier). When I filter in the main QGIS window it compiles all the records for a species onto the map, but I can't figure out how to use a filter for the Atlas. Filtering on the name in the Atlas window only does the first species. Not sure how to post images - today was my first post.

Comment: Unfortunatly, the Atlas filtering only works for generating maps in different locations with the same content, not the same location with different content.

Comment: graahh. time out. ok again. Unfortunatly, the Atlas only works for generating maps in different locations with the same content, not the same location with different content. I fear you will end up with 325 different layers derived from your species layer, switching on and off for printing. At least that was the solution for me on a similar problem ... with 13 species. I used the "Split Layer by attribute"-plugin for that, which generates filtered copies of the original layer. With so many different layers, I fear QGIS will go down the sink ...

Comment: @BerndV. That's not strictly true - you can definitely use an Atlas for a static map location but varying content. Use a rule based (or data defined) symbology and take advantage of the "attribute( $atlasfeature, 'field_name' )" expression function.